# increase performance while retrieving thousand of record from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have one table that contain more that 40 thousand record when I retrieve record that satisfy particular condition it takes so much time.

Is there any solution to increase performance ?

Comment: what is "more that 4 lack record"?

Comment: I assume you have set up an index?

Comment: 40000 rows is nothing in terms of databases. You are probably doing something terrible to make your database such a slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a lot of querying based on another column that isn't your primary key, try adding an index to that column you are putting in your `WHERE` clause.

Also, optimizing `JOIN`s will help if you are using any.

Comment: Index improve performance while retrieving data from database but takes time while enter data into table.

Comment: Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexes to increase the performance, check [7.5.3. How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also run explain command, for example 'explain select * from mytable where someField = 'Something'; ' and see what it returns, but I'd think 'index' solution should be good enough.

Also, maybe you could consider splitting table into few simple tables. I don't know what is your structure, but I have seen in the past examples, where people would keep redundant data in the same table, for example: have customer name and address in the same table, where you could split it into customers and addresses, and then perform queries on one table only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right that people should normalize their data, that is just DBA 101. But his problem is with data retrieval performance, normalization doesn't help there! Quite the contrary :)

Comment: Well, it helped me with the performance on some legacy project I was working couple years ago, but I suppose each case is different :)

Answer (score 0):

First step: find out whether or not the time is being spent running the query, or transferring the data back to you.

How long does it take to run this query-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
( [your query that returns 40k rows] ) AS butts;
```

If it's quick, then most of the time is probably spent transferring the data back into your client.  Look into using MySQL's compression.

If the server is taking a long time with the query, it's probably something that can be fixed with proper normalization and index use, as the other people here have mentioned.  For help optimizing a specific query, you should paste the CREATE TABLEs for all the tables involved, and the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple optimization for SQL is to return fewer columns from a table. If you only display two fields from the SQL table, don't retrieve the rest of the fields until someone needs to see them for a specific record.